# Triggering JavaScript based on  a (hash) link component 

Tags: jquery, hash, reload

I have a simple jquery function to show a video when #showvideo is presentin the url bar, which works when you type the url and visit file.html#showvideo, but not when a link is clicked. Do I need to set up some kind of listener event to trigger this? The #video link will be embedded in a vimeo video, so I can't change the  tag

```
$(function(){
    if(window.location.hash == '#showvideo') {
        $(".current #video").show();
    }
})
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you've got there.  What happens when you run `$(".current #video").show();` in the console?  And does the #video object exist at document ready?

Answer (score 2):

You need to watch for onhashchange.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange

Here's a cross-browser-compatible library/polyfill:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: any ideas why this wont work?


 function showvideo() {
     if(window.location.hash == '#showvideo') {
      console.log('video = 1');
     }
 }

 $(document).ready(function(){
  showvideo();
  $(window).hashchange(showvideo());
 })

Comment: Sure. $(window).hashchange(showvideo());  should be  window.onhashchange = showvideo.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/mstauffer/4MDgZ/3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch for hash changes. There are libraries such as [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) that can help with this. Some browsers have the [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) event that you can listen on. For browsers that don't you can set up a poll timer with a short interval to check the hash for changes.

Comment: any ideas why this wont work?


 function showvideo() {
     if(window.location.hash == '#showvideo') {
      console.log('video = 1');
     }
 }

 $(document).ready(function(){
  showvideo();
  $(window).hashchange(showvideo());
 })

Comment: Change `$(window).hashchange(showvideo())` to `$(window).hashchange(showvideo)`